# Best way to space out execution / requests (for a web crawler)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a web crawler. It grabs a main page, which has about 50 links. Then I need to do 2 requests for each link. I dont want to make 101 requests within a few seconds. What is the best way to randomly space these out? I want to somewhat mimic human activity.

```
urls.each do |url|
    # Do Something
    sleep([1,2,3,4,5].sample)
end
```

This will work, but is this the best was to do it? Let's say this takes about 1 hour to run, will the server become slow to respond when when it's sleeping?

Answer (score 0):

Mimicking human behavior is very hard. It's impossible if you're requesting literally every single link on a website anyway. I would probably just request one page per second. The server will not be impacted at all by a thread that's currently sleeping.